# too much UDP traffic from unknown IPs

Tags: networking, server

I found on my server a big activity
60Mbit of bandwidth using just for UDP connections

nither 172.37.3.11.2001 nor 239.1.3.3.1234 are not my IP even they are not in my network.

Could you please explain what it could be and how to solve it :(
Thank you very much

## tcpdump -i eth5

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth5, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
17:14:35.944467 IP 172.37.3.11.2001 > 239.1.3.7.1234: UDP, length 1316
17:14:35.944511 IP 172.37.3.11.2001 > 239.1.3.15.1234: UDP, length 1316
17:14:35.944533 IP 172.37.3.11.2001 > 239.1.3.11.1234: UDP, length 1316
17:14:35.944589 IP 172.37.3.11.2001 > 239.1.3.5.1234: UDP, length 1316
17:14:35.944600 IP 172.37.3.11.2001 > 239.1.3.1.1234: UDP, length 1316
17:14:35.944602 IP 172.37.3.11.2001 > 239.1.3.7.1234: UDP, length 1316
17:14:35.944656 IP 172.37.3.11.2001 > 239.1.3.3.1234: UDP, length 1316
17:14:35.944701 IP 172.37.3.11.2001 > 239.1.3.1.1234: UDP, length 1316
17:14:35.944766 IP 172.37.3.11.2001 > 239.1.3.7.1234: UDP, length 1316
17:14:35.944833 IP 172.37.3.11.2001 > 239.1.3.3.1234: UDP, length 1316
17:14:35.944851 IP 172.37.3.11.2001 > 239.1.3.1.1234: UDP, length 1316
17:14:35.944929 IP 172.37.3.11.2001 > 239.1.3.7.1234: UDP, length 1316
17:14:35.945001 IP 172.37.3.11.2001 > 239.1.3.1.1234: UDP, length 1316
17:14:35.945028 IP 172.37.3.11.2001 > 239.1.3.3.1234: UDP, length 1316
17:14:35.945092 IP 172.37.3.11.2001 > 239.1.3.5.1234: UDP, length 1316
17:14:35.945093 IP 172.37.3.11.2001 > 239.1.3.7.1234: UDP, length 1316
17:14:35.945158 IP 172.37.3.11.2001 > 239.1.3.1.1234: UDP, length 1316
17:14:35.945223 IP 172.37.3.11.2001 > 239.1.3.3.1234: UDP, length 1316
17:14:35.945258 IP 172.37.3.11.2001 > 239.1.3.7.1234: UDP, length 1316
17:14:35.945286 IP 172.37.3.11.2001 > 239.1.3.15.1234: UDP, length 1316
```

with -vv

```
17:48:53.978797 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 1344)
    172.37.3.11.2001 > 239.1.3.14.1234: [no cksum] UDP, length 1316
17:48:53.978846 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 1344)
    172.37.3.11.2001 > 239.1.3.12.1234: [no cksum] UDP, length 1316
17:48:53.979075 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 1344)
    172.37.3.11.2001 > 239.1.3.74.1234: [no cksum] UDP, length 1316
17:48:53.979213 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 1344)
    172.37.3.11.2001 > 239.1.3.38.1234: [no cksum] UDP, length 1316
17:48:53.979275 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 1344)
    172.37.3.11.2001 > 239.1.3.42.1234: [no cksum] UDP, length 1316
17:48:53.979332 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 1344)
    172.37.3.11.2001 > 239.1.3.40.1234: [no cksum] UDP, length 1316
17:48:53.979351 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 1344)
    172.37.3.11.2001 > 239.1.3.32.1234: [no cksum] UDP, length 1316
17:48:53.979405 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 1344)
    172.37.3.11.2001 > 239.1.3.16.1234: [no cksum] UDP, length 1316
17:48:53.979789 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 0, offset 0, flags [none], proto UDP (17), length 1344)
```

Comment: Well the 172.37.3.11 is a TMobile IP in Bellevue Washington, and the other is a reserved from multicast.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I found it by WhoIs, and the other address is some IPTV Russian channel,

Comment: Just 60 mbit it is too much and I am trying to understand what is it and is somebody hack the server :(

Comment: What kind of security are your running on your server?

Comment: Actually I am very new in server, so by iptables I closed ports as was in article on digital ocean, leave opened just 80, 8080, 443, for http(s), 53 for ns,

Comment: Changed SSH port, and closed 22 port,  and install sshtobann for prevent multiple incorrect connections. This server is using as nginx proxy caching server and nothing more.

Comment: https://www.thefanclub.co.za/how-to/how-secure-ubuntu-1604-lts-server-part-1-basics Good place to start for server security. I don't work for/at The Fan Club

Comment: Thank you very much. My question was not how to protect my server, it was how can I understand that I was hacked and how to find it. But anyway Thanx for usefull link